# Facebook connect access_token

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

Hi i ve got the same issue than this guy:

[Acces token from facebook is not retrived for sign up? access_token (trying to get propert of non object )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174363/acces-token-from-facebook-is-not-retrived-for-sign-up-access-token-trying-to-g)

Apparently he found a solution but I do not clearly understand it. 
Just need you help to understand what should i do.

Problem is access_token trying to get property of a non object when i try to log in with facebook connect.

the solution I don't understand is this one.

"Its was an database error due to session have not created due to facebook app not live."

Answer (score 0):

"Its was an database error due to session have not created due to facebook app not live."

Make sure your facebook app is not in sandbox mode. Also if you are developing at localhost it might have some problems with the facebook api.

Comment: i am not developing on localhost and facebook app is not in sandbox mode.